# How to sort new data for display?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am new to SQL. I have a table called `Categories` with 3 columns:

```
id int(25)
category varchar(25)
subcategory varchar(25)
```

I would like to add a new subcategory "Real Estate Agency" in the category "Accommodation". When I do that, the new subcategory appears at the bottom of my table:

[[image: Screenshot 1]

All my data have an increase ID (1, 2, 3, 4) so when I add new data it takes the new ID order ( for instance : 157 ). If I understand correctly the ordering is done by the ID.

The problem is that now the new sub-category appears in my website drop-down menu but it's not in alphabetical order. It appears at the end of the category list:

[[image: Screenshot 2]

I have been searching in my SQL for Beginners book, in Google and Stack Exchange but I didn't find help for my issue.

If someone has a good idea how to solve this I would appreciate it.

Comment: This sounds like a software design problem, not a database problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so why don't you just use the `ORDER BY` clause? Like you have said, by default the `SELECT` statement will return our data ordering by ID, so you need to specify that you want your own order.

```
SELECT id, category, subcategory
FROM Category
ORDER BY subcategory ASC
```

The `ASC` means ascendant order [that's default behavior], so it will return ordered from A-Z. You can specify `DESC` that refers to descendant order, which will return ordered from Z-A.

P.S.: I saw you have you categories and subcategories in the same table, and they have a one to many relationship, shouldn't you normalize that? It will help you while you data in that table get bigger. [Normalization of Database](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)